# Get GPS on mobile browser without HTML5 Geolocation?

Tags: mobile, browser, gps, mobile-browser

I'm wondering if there's a way to get GPS/location data (non-IP based location) on mobile browsers **without** having to use HTML5 Geolocation API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the GPS Location in an Browser you have to use the Geolocation API. There is no other way to get the exact Location without it.